# "Thanks to .." vs "..make it possible for .."

Tags: meaning

Do the below sentences mean the same ?

The TV sport channel  made it possible for us to watch on tennis tournament in Dubai.

Thanks to the TV sport channel  we can watch on tennis tournament in Dubai.

Comment: They mean pretty much the same thing, although "Thanks to..." is less formal.  By the way, it should be "watch a tennis tournament" or "watch the tennis tournament", but not "watch *on*".

Answer (score 1):

They are somewhat different.

> The TV sport channel **made it possible** for us to watch *the* tennis tournament in Dubai.

*possibility* is like *availability*. I means you could watch it, compared to some other area where you could not watch it.

> **Thanks** to the TV sport channel we can watch *the* tennis tournament in Dubai.

*thanks* is like *appreciation*. You are happy that the TV channel did what they did so you could watch it.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are actually grammatically incorrect. You could instead write for the first sentence

> The T.V. sport channel made it possible for us to watch the tennis tournament in Dubai.

and for the second sentence

> Thanks to the TV sport channel, we can watch the tennis tournament in Dubai.

Written like that, they do indeed mean about the same thing.